# How to preserve some cookies after firefox is closed?

Tags: php, firefox, cookies, yii

Test case:

*Firefox 16.0.1*

*MAC OSX LION*

The following works on latest Safari, Chrome. Not Firefox.

The point is to display a video for the first user visit. If different then the first visit, no video is show.

So, on this web application we have set the following:

*on controller/index:*

```
Yii::app()->request->cookies['first'] = new CHttpCookie('first', (isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['first']) ? Yii::app()->request->cookies['first']->value+1 : 1));
            $cookie = Yii::app()->request->cookies['first'];
                    $cookie->expire = time() + (60*60*24*7);


Yii::app()->session['first'] =  (isset(Yii::app()->session['first']) ? Yii::app()->session['first']+1 : 1);
```

*on main.php:*

```
 'session'=>array(
  'timeout'=>604800
 ),
```

However, each time we close firefox and we re-opened it, it resets the cookie and session value.

Comment: Do your browser accepts cookies?

Comment: @Denis Ermolin: Yes. During the navigation tests if we DON'T close the browser, we can see cookies are set. Only when we close and we reopen the cookies seems to reset.

Comment: You're cookie is likely set to delete on browser close. No specified delete date, likely.

Comment: @bigman I've made no specific configuration regarding that on this new installed browser. And, isn't true that, IF we define an expiration, then the browser SHOULDN'T do that ?

Comment: Well, is your app ignoring the set cookie and just creating a new one? Or is the cookie actually gone?  You should close your browser open it up and before going to your site, check for the existence of that cookie. If it's still there, your app might be overwriting it with a new session value.

Comment: On Chrome it works. On Safari it works. Only firefox it doesn´t.

Comment: Then that's likely what @LastCoder mentioned below.

Comment: @bigman : no dice. I have no privacy mode enable.

Comment: @MEM set an additional cookie and see if that gets taken down also

Comment: are there other cookies entact? From other sites?

Comment: Yup. they do appear. From other sites, I can see them. :/

Comment: Do me a favor, comment out that code and just try a `setcookie()` approach for a second. It's obviously not the browser.

Comment: @bigman Setcookie DOES INDEED worked. :) - Something Yii related should be not working then. (99% probability on our code)

Comment: Whew, good, makes me happy ;)

Comment: @MEM Take a look at my latest answer

Answer (score 1):

You're session is a cookie. The "session cookie" expires when the browser closes (no matter the server side timeout you place on it, since this happens client side).

The request->cookies when set with a proper expiration date should be fine. However, these will be removed too if the client browser is set to privacy mode.

**EDIT** It appears you never actually set the cookie with the expiration date. My PHP is a bit rusty, but the following should be correct.

```
// get the cookie value if it exists
$oldVal = isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['first']) ? Yii::app()->request->cookies['first']->value : 0;
// set the cookie
$cookie = new CHttpCookie('first', $value);
$cookie->expire = time()+60*60*24*180; 
Yii::app()->request->cookies['first'] = $cookie;
// other page logic
if($oldVal == 0) {
    // show the video
}
```

Comment: Just checked. No privacy mode is enable on this browser configuration.

Comment: @MEM - have users authenticate (so you know the unique user id of the person) and set the "already_watched" value bit in a database table.

Comment: @LastCoder for every user? even anons? Negative.

Comment: @bigman - You want to track people accessing the site anonymously? Do you see the contradiction there, I guess you could use "super cookies" (i.e. combining cookies with flash and/or java objects in an attempt to stay resident on user's machines)

Comment: lol, take it easy.  In this situation, I'm saying taking it to the DB is not necessary.

Comment: @LastCoder Your last statement was correct: "when set with the proper expiration date should be fine" and indeed it should. However it doesn't. Also, the FF is storing other cookies just not those. So, the issue must NOT be on the browser. So something must be happening that we are not getting, hence, no need to registering users. If, however, and obviously we will, have users that DO navigate on Privacy mode, when... it's their choice. We are fine with that. ;)

Comment: @MEM - Looks like you never actually setting the cookie with the updated expiration. You're grabbing the cookie you just added and modified the expiration, but according to Yii's documentation the cookie doesn't exist yet. http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/152/cookie-management-in-yii/#hh8

Answer (score 0):

Likely an issue with `Yii` somewhere. Try `setcookie()` just to make sure its not a browser issue.

Since you are doing..

`Yii::app()->request->cookies['first'] = new CHttpCookie(....`

Look's like you're setting an existing cookie to a new cookie.

```
if (!isset(Yii::app()->request->cookies['first'])) {

     $cookie = new CHttpCookie('first', 1);
     $cookie->expire = time() + (60*60*24*7);

}
```